# How can I update a document in a collection as soon as a new document is created with a reference that particular document in seperate collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create a new contact. this contact is going to have a schema like this below

When I create this new contact I will be sending a group, firstName, lastName, and _user reference.The group will have been already created(see Schema below) beforehand and will have its on ObjectId.

So hen I create this contactSchema, how am I able to update the already created GroupSchema so it know this particular ObjectId of this Contact Schema now has a reference to the GroupSchema.... I would love a good explanation

I am using Node.js Express and MongoDB

```
const contactSchema = new Schema({
  
    group: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'group', 
        required: [true, 'Group must not be empty']
    }],
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String, 
    
    
    _user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
```

GroupSchema (this will have already been created)

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const groupSchema = new Schema ({
    title: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    contacts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'contact' }],
    _user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('group', groupSchema)
```

Here is my current controller function for creating a new contact,
can I somehow add the logic in this controller function?

```
const createContact = async (req, res) => {
                const { phone_number, country, phone_type, group, firstName, lastName, company, email} = req.body
                const newContact = new Contact({
                    phone_number: phone_number,
                    country: country,
                    group: group,
                    phone_type: phone_type,
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    company: company,
                    email: email,
                    _user: req.user.id
                })
                const createdContact = await newContact.save()
                res.status(201).json(createdContact)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post this solution that I found, I will update this more once im smarter...

Here is my controller function below

```
     const createContact = async (req, res) => {
                const { group, firstName, lastName, company, email} = req.body
 

                const newContact = new Contact({
                                                                          
                       //[    // group array of objects as they come in from above
                      //  {
                     //    contacts: [],
                     //    _id: '60d2d',
                    //    title: 'vacant',
                    //    created: '2021-07-27'
                    //  },
                    //  {
                   //    contacts: [],
                   //    _id: '60ff4',
                   //    title: 'yellow belts',
                   //    created: '2021-07-26'
                    //  }
                     //]
                   
                    group: group, // this group coming in is an array of objects, each object has array of contacts
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    company: company,
                    email: email,
                    _user: req.user.id
                })
                const createdContact = await newContact.save() // I now have access to this newly created objectId
                console.log(createdContact._id) // we need to push this into each groups contact array
                const GroupId = group.map(groups =>  groups._id) // map over groups array to get the objectIds so we can query the Groups collection by id
                const ChosenGroups = await (await Group.updateMany({ '_id': { $in: GroupId}}, {$set: {contacts : createdContact._id}}));
                console.log(ChosenGroups)
              
           
                res.status(201).json(createdContact)
            }
```